# putting where condition in sphinx and how to remove setlimit in sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a `phone` table which contains 3 columns namely `id, brand, and model`. Then I have an another table named `my_devices` which contains my specific list of devices and has the same number of columns with same names. I am using `Sphinx` for matching both the tables i.e for every entry in my_devices give me the corresponding match in phone table.

my php code is this :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root",  "", "merge") or die("error connecting database".mysqli_error($con));
require_once('sphinxapi.php');
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("127.0.0.1", 9312); // NOT "localhost" under Windows 7!
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$s->SetLimits(0,10000);
$no=0;
$imi_model="A110";
$result = $s->Query($imi_model);
var_dump($result); echo "<pre>";
if ($result['total'] > 0) {
    echo "****";
echo 'Total: ' . $result['total'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'Total Found: ' . $result['total_found'] . "<br>\n";
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>No.</td><td>ID</td><td>brand</td><td>model</td></tr>';

foreach ($result['matches'] as $id => $otherStuff) 
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select *  from pda where id = $id"));
// var_dump($row); exit;
extract($row);
++ $no;
echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$id</td><td>$brand</td><td>$model</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
} else {
echo 'No results found';
}
?>
```

now this code is giving output like this :

```
No. ID         brand         model
1   50         Acer Acer     Iconia Tab A110 16GB
2   51         Acer Acer     Iconia Tab A110 8GB
3   2752       Micromax      Micromax A110 Canvas 2
4   3508       Nokia         Nokia X Dual SIM A110 (Nokia Normandy)
```

My sphinx configuration looks like this :

```
#
# Minimal Sphinx configuration sample (clean, simple, functional)
#

source sphinx_merge
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        =
    sql_db          = merge
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id, brand, model \
        FROM pda

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM pda WHERE id=$id
}


index merge_indexing
{
    source          = sphinx_merge
    path            = c:\sphinx\data\test1
    docinfo         = extern
    charset_type        = sbcs
}   


index testrt
{
    type            = rt
    rt_mem_limit        = 32M

    path            = c:\sphinx\data\testrt
    charset_type        = utf-8

    rt_field        = title
    rt_field        = content
    rt_attr_uint        = gid
}


indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 32M
}


searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = c:\sphinx\log\searchd.log
    query_log       = c:\sphinx\log\query.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    max_children        = 30
    pid_file        = c:\sphinx\log\searchd.pid
    max_matches     = 1000
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = c:\sphinx\data
}
```

I have following questions :

1 ) what should I change in the query so that I can get the result of a particular brand like only `A110 of acer` . and where should I put this change in my sql query in php or in configuration file.

2) how can I remove the `setLimit` in sphinx. I have put the limit to a very large value though. But it can create problems when I have a huge dataset

Comment: /why/ do you want to remove the limit? Sounds like you thinking about it wrong.

Comment: If i set some limit then it is showing me less number of results. suppose If i want to loop through the result set and the limit is set 10. Then i will be able to iterate through only 10 results not more

Comment: *why* do you want to iterate in the list of all results? This was @barryhunter question... Typically you paginate the results, which means that you only need 10-50 results (per page).

Comment: Sir, I want to update another table for every hit I found through sphinx

Comment: In that case will just either have to 1) do it lots of small queries. or 2) jsut set a really high max_matches. `->setLimits(0,1000000,1000000); The fact that such queries will be slow, might not actully matter if its a infrequently run batch process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use the @field limit operator...

```
$result = $s->Query("@brand acer @model A110");
```

2) You can't remove the limit. Will always be subject to max_matches. But making max_matches very big will lead to all queries being slow and wasteful of memory.

Comment: Sir, I have already tried the solution that you have given but it is not working.

Comment: thanku very much sir. Your answer is correct. I was doing something else wrong